# PHP / GD imagedashedline invisible or not drawn

Tags: php, gd

I'm drawing some boxes onto a canvas but there seems to be an issue with imagedashedline. Dashed lines seem to be invisible except for cases where the line isn't horizontal. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Example code

```
$width = 204;
$height = 317;

$canvas = imagecreate($width, $height);

$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 2555, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0, 0, 0);

$topLeft     = 2;
$topRight    = 2;

$bottomLeft  = $width-2;
$bottomRight = $height-2;

imagesetthickness($canvas, 1);

// parallel line, solid
imageline($canvas, 0, 101, 204, 101, $black);

// parallel line, should be dashed, fail
imagedashedline($canvas, 0, 121, 204, 121, $black);

// parallel line should be dashed, works
imagedashedline($canvas, 0, 0, 204, 305, $black);

imagejpeg($canvas,'dashes.jpg');
imagedestroy($canvas)
```

Output

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments on [`imagedashedline()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedashedline.php). Also, it's deprecated, but you can use combination of `imagesetstyle()` and `imageline()` instead.